# Cordova detect if device can place phone calls

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm using [cordova-network-information](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-network-information) to check if the device is offline or online. The problem with this plugin is that a device can be on WIFI and SIM, but then the faster WIFI would be returned as the current network.

How do I detect if my device is 'phone call' capable?

Comment: I guess you'll need a plugin for that. [This one](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim) looks promising...

Comment: Indeed, thanks, I'm gonna test it out

Comment: It's actual just want I needed. You can post your answer if you want me to validate it out and close this question...

Comment: Unfortunally it doesn't seem to work for iOS yet... But thanks